# AngularJs inline editing insert html tag

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create an inline editable content in angularJs that could insert also formatted html tag.

I have created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cHgr6BxzoT3LWhc35kmX?p=preview

But when I try to insert some html tag like for example:

```
<b>test</b>
```

I'd like to see a bold text, but it only show plain text and not html...

[EDIT]

Probably I cannot explain well what I want. I would like to crate a simple html editor, which can modify a text and for example add link, bold text, heading tags etc... simply writing the html tag and compile in the page.

The answers are right if I would like to output a text from my controller, but I wanna make this editable.

Comment: try `ngBindHtmlUnsafe` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Comment: I've updated my plunker: does not seems to work properly...

Comment: try updating with this works => `$scope.name = '<b>World</b>';`

Comment: reply me back so, i can post the answer

Comment: I've tried....but I want to make editable content generates new html tag to show formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your element focus/blur for your directive you can achieve what you want.

When you edit it though, I have it switch back into the "html edit mode"

```
  element.bind("focus", function(){
    scope.name = scope.name.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    scope.$apply();
  })
  element.bind("blur", function() {
    scope.name = element[0].innerHTML.replace(/[&]lt[;]/g, "<").replace(/[&]gt[;]/g, ">");
    scope.$apply();
  });
```

updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/cfSBctBbK6cpwfKrwwWf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is a directive for this. Instead of using **ng-bind** use **ng-bind-html-unsafe**. Then you can pass to your model literal html like this:

> `$scope.name = '<b>World</b>';`

Comment: from your plunkr i can see that you are not only trying to bind to model but you want to wrap it into directive with contenteditable. in that case have a look at $compile() function [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile]

in your link() function in directive you have to call it over template html so that your binding expressions become "alive"

Comment: or jusr use "template" property of your directive definition instead of link() function. if you insert your html in "template" it is compilled automatically. then you also need to bind your scope properties with "scope" directive property like scope: {name: '='}

Answer (score 0):

You should use or inspire yourself with [CodeMirror UI directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror), from [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).

Made a working [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJLTXE?p=preview), but the dependencies are not good.